# Fail to connect to an Access data base using pyodbc python

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to an Access data base as follows...

```
    Import pyodbc
    driver='Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)'
    filepath=r'D:\DOCS CCAAMAÑO\PROGRAMAS PYTHON\Acces\Cons_Fluids.accdb'
    conn=pyodbc.connect(driver=driver,DBQ=filepath)
```

But I got this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DOCS CCAAMAÑO\PROGRAMAS PYTHON\Acces\Test_db\test_db.py", line 14, in <module>
    conn=pyodbc.connect(driver=access_driver,DBQ=filepath)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] No se puede cargar el controlador especificado debido al error del sistema  1114: Error en una rutina de inicialización de biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos (DLL). (Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb), C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\VFS\\ProgramFilesCommonX64\\Microsoft Shared\\Office16\\ACEODBC.DLL). (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I must say that I'm working with python 3.8 (64bit) and MS Office 365 where MS Access is 64bit as well.
I already installed the Access driver "Microsoft Access database engine 2016".
Additionally, I previously run this code and worked well, but now I really don't understand whats going on.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Sounds like an installation issue. I'd do a full reinstall of both Office and the database engine. These tend to occur when someone messes with the drivers, which can happen when using an Office version that comes with the database engine and then installing the database engine as well, trying to run 64-bit and 32-bit simultaneously, using multiple versions of Office simultaneously, and in some other conditions.

Comment: @ErikA, I installed again the Access driver and now is working well. I think that was the problem. Thanks a lot.